# Is there an image or video of Star Wars character Domine (or Demine) Lithe?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, the-rise-of-skywalker

I have watched *The Rise of Skywalker* more than a few times, plus some behind-the-scenes videos, trying to spot character Domine (or Demine) Lithe, a pilot of the Resistance during the First Order-Resistance war, but without success. Can someone provide – from any source – a picture or video of this character?

This character was performed by U.S. actress Carolyn Hennesy whose voice also portrayed General Leia Organa in *LEGO Star Wars: All-Stars* and *Star Wars Resistance*.

Here Finn with a female pilot that that resembles Carolyn Hennesy.

[image: Still picture of The Rise of Skywalker]

Comment: The actress who portrayed Lithe was [Carolyn Hennesy](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/Carolyn_Hennesy_2010_Daytime_Emmy_Awards.jpg) - I've contacted her to ask where she appears in the film

Comment: @Valorum - She's listed in the credits shortly after Warwick Davis and his son so if we can assume listing by appearance, it will be in the final 20 minutes.

Comment: The character in your image has quite distinctive teeth that don't look like Carolyn Hennesy's. It's possible she was wearing fakes, but I don't think she would be

Comment: @Valorum - I found another pilot with closest possible match with Carolyn Hennesy.

Comment: @Valorum: How can you possibly tecognize any teeth in that blurry mouth?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Because I've got the Blu-ray

Answer (score 8):

I believe this is her, seen running toward the Falcon as it lands (on fire) at the start of the film.

[image: Rebels running out of a ship, with a redhead leading them]

[image: gif of the many rebels in the above picture]

Comment: TBH I'm not entirely convinced. She's listed as a pilot and this is a ground-crew, but the number of Rebel redheads is precisely one.